# Power BI convert both HH:MM:SS format and decimal duration format to MM:SS format

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-cleaning, powerbi-desktop, data-transform

PLease review the screenshot.

[image]

The column contains both HH:MM:SS format and decimal duration in hours format with extra leading zeros. They are both in Text format.

How to covert them to MM:SS format? Like for example 01:28:10 should be 88:10

I'm quite confused by how to achieve that by using DAX.

I have tried multiple possible solutions but none worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following function to only convert the format if it is in HH:MM:SS:

```
New Format = IF(len(Sheet1[ACD Time])=8,
            FORMAT(VALUE(LEFT(Sheet1[ACD Time],2))*60 + VALUE(MID(Sheet1[ACD Time],4,2)),"General Number")&":"&RIGHT(Sheet1[ACD Time],2),
                Sheet1[ACD Time])
```

**Reference:**

Format function https://dax.guide/format/

[image]

Comment: Just sent you a Linkedin request

Comment: Hi, you got other issue cannot solved with the formula?

Comment: Yeah, brother. I'm good with Python and R, but less experience in DAX. Hope to learn from the best like you my friend. If you don't mind, please accept my friend request on Linkedin

Comment: Sure, although I not sure what linkend can do about it...I also learning Python and R currently haha.